# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time for the site's first new cycle of Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- academic websites and resources
- interesting campus story blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1478).

Comment: Are there any plans to create a new thread for 2016, or should we keep using this one?

Comment: @pintoch We're making some sidebar changes that'll affect the ad size, and those are coming out mid-January. We'll be resetting ads then.

Comment: In case someone was searching, the new thread is here: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/community-promotion-ads-2016

Answer (score 33):

[image: PHD Comics]

Comment: [In 2014](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/ads/display/907), this ad had far more clicks/day than any of the others (by a factor of ~5)

Comment: Academia.SE (and the whole SE generally) is already a procrastinating network.

Answer (score 33):

[image: arXiv.org: the biggest open-access e-print repository for maths and physics]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Retraction watch]

Comment: Should we ask someone there for a high-res version of their logo?

Comment: You got there first!  I was thinking of adding this this morning, but wasn't sure about the permissions on the logo...

Answer (score 26):

[image: Internet Archive WaybackMachine]

Answer (score 21):

[image: rOpenSci - Join Us!]

Answer (score 16):

[image: That's called negative income!]

Comment: The mouseover text for this ad is "Tagline to show on mouseover". Might want to get that looked at!

Answer (score 14):

[image: Open Data]

Comment: Academics often need data for research purposes. Also, data questions are [sometimes](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5190) asked on Academia, then moved to Open Data: Better let people know that Open Data is a better place for such questions.

Answer (score 13):

[image: What if? Serious scientific answers to absurd hypothetical questions]

Comment: A little blurry. Could use some improvements in readability.

Comment: @Compass If it starts getting upvotes, I'll get a higher-res image

Comment: Well if you gave it a higher res image it would get more upvotes :D

Comment: @jakebeal It seems those upvotes materialized.

Comment: @E.P. And back in mid-January when I tried to get a higher-res image, I failed, unfortunately.

Comment: @jakebeal I found the ad hard to read, so I took a high resolution image and made the text larger. (Unfortunately that meant changing the cover design.) The ad is double size (same as the [bounty ad](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1615/41580)), which displays nicer on retina displays. Feel free to roll the edit back if you prefer the previous version.

Comment: @Earthliŋ It's great, thanks!

Comment: Hi. I have copy-pasted [this in Physics Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7177/46399), with citation (of course).

Comment: @TheDarkSide Cool!  That would be an obvious other fun place for it.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Open Science Federation]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Pubpeer: post-publication peer review]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Expats.SE]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Mythology.SE]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Answer (score 9):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/academia.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://academia.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Ad for Writers]

Answer (score 8):

[image: If you want down-to-earth answers to your questions]

Answer (score 7):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 6):

[image: NASA Astronomy Picture of the Day]

Answer (score 6):

[image: For people looking to improve their productivity]

Answer (score 6):

[image: HSM]

Answer (score 3):

[image: SciRate]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Participate on Law Stack Exchange!]

Comment: Yes, it's true!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Latin Language proposal on Area 51]

Comment: My impression is that the Latin Language site would be happy to receive questions about current usage of Latin, including the usage of Latin-rooted terminology in academic disciplines.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 1):

[image: New site for researches interested in structure determination]

Answer (score -4):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Comment: Downvotes on proposed ads just mean, "This isn't something I want to support through advertising on this site." It doesn't have anything to do with rules.

Comment: @sepideh page not found

Comment: thanks, but I'll have to let you down. Sorry I can't help. I'm not in the field. And I don't downvote this.

Answer (score -5):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]