# Idea for ad about health in this site?

Tags: discussion

A long long time ago, when the Earth was still in darkness, and the human kind was not so bright, one brave alien had came to the Area and laid the first brick (or the first click) of an architechture. That creature didn't think its action had any impact. But one told ten, ten told eleven, and luckily they don't use adblock, together they came and laid their bricks (or clicks) onto the first one. Throughout many storms, amazingly the bunch of bricks (or clicks) became a glorious and beautiful castle. The citizen in that castle call themselves as academian, and name the castle as Academia.

.

Ok, forget the story. [Health SE](http://health.stackexchange.com) is a newborn site of the SE system, and just like Academia SE a long long time ago, it needs to attract new people. According to the [stat](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health), there is only two Okays and the rest are Need Works. But what bored me most is the answered question rate: 73% (it's 75% just a couple days ago). You know why: more people ask but the number of answerers doesn't increase. Not to mention the endemic of the field, the site itself [strongly encourage](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers/4#4) to have source in the answer, since it's the only way to know how good the answer is.

But [you don't need to be a doctor to answer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322/who-are-you-and-why-are-you-here). I don't know much how the healthcare system works, but I believe that doctors are not the only one who can answer questions about health. It just need to reach the right person. And I think in Academia, there are a lot of right ones can help.

.

My [current ad](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1773/14341) ("Behind every PhD is always have a doctor there) is meant to be fun, but there is a downvote for it. This may mean that they may not want to see it here. But why? A typical grad student need to spend 60 hours per week to work, so being healthy is very important, why does that one not want to see it here? I conclude that because the ad itself, not the site, is bad. So I want to improve it.

I remember an old psychology technique that every teacher must know: tell something to them, they will easily forget it; but make them tell themselves, they will remember it, or feel attach to it. And since the ads are chosen by the community, why not let them create it for themselves? After all, it's their idea, how can they hate it?

So here, this is the question: Do you have any idea for an ad of Health SE?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask this on the Healt.se meta?

Comment: I  don't think so. The audiences of the ad is in here, Academia, so it's better to ask here. Plus, I want to see the reaction/feedback because I just come up this idea.

Comment: AArhg an entire site for consequence-free Internet doctors! On my way to downvote the add.

Comment: @CapeCode i see your downvote...

Comment: @CapeCode The purpose of the whole SE (which Health is a member) is providing knowledge. It can be in the form of advises, methods, or cures, but it must tell why it works. There is no clear cut what question is not potentially dangerous, but if it clearly requires a doctor, then it should be closed. In a good form answer, it will have a reference to back it up [...] (too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer in [OMG… A site about Health?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/357/99). There are a lot of good answers there.)